# Django annotate Count query output

Tags: python, django, annotations, count

I have confusion in result of these queries:

```
>>> [f.count for f in Favourite.objects.annotate(count = Count('object_id'))]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and second one is

```
>>> [f['count'] for f in Favourite.objects.values('object_id').annotate(count=Count('object_id'))]
[1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3]
```

but according to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) first query should work fine, and `Favourite` object have count of `object_id`.

Can anyone explain why the second query is working, but not the first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is doing a `group by` on object_id. This is the expected behaviour. The first one is simply counting object_id for each row in the database.

Comment: @Ahsan: The example you refer to in the docs uses annotation on a `ManyToManyField` so you can get counts > 1 for a single record, without grouping. For "normal" fields which are actual columns in the db table, you can obviously have just a count of 1 value per row without grouping by something.

Comment: @Béres Botond: I have also tried same as docs `>>> [ge.c for ge in Album.objects.annotate(c=Count('genre'))]`
output: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` here `genre` have `ManyToManyField ` relationshis with `Album`. And it works when i did `>>> [ge['c'] for ge in Album.objects.values('genre').annotate(c=Count('genre'))]`
output: `[1, 6, 1]`